# Django Angular File Upload - Upload works in Postman but does not with angular 7

Tags: django, angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, form-data

I have Django Backend that accepts File with other data as a request.
When I use File Upload API from Postman to submit File and other form data. [Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6FMb.png) It works fine and Prints

```
<QueryDict: {u'csv': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: log_2018_10_09- 
11_57_16_Summary_subject23_hrm.csv (text/csv)>], u'device_name': 
[u'Zephyr']}>
```

and file successfully get stored.

But when I am trying to do it with Angular it logs empty object.
Below is my Angular Code.

```
// HTML
<input hidden type="file" id="csv" name="csv" accept=".csv" 
(change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>

// On Change Method
onFileChange(evt: any) {
console.log(this.fileNames.toString());
if (evt.target.files && evt.target.files[0]) {
  console.log(evt.target.files[0]);
  this.file = evt.target.files[0];

  this.fileNames.push({ name: this.file.name });
  this.processFile(this.file).then(data => this.newMethod(data));

  this.showUploadButton = false;
  this.showFileName = true;
}
console.log(this.fileNames[0].name);
}

processFile(file) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});
}

private newMethod(data: any): void | PromiseLike<void> {
// this.uploadData.append('csv', data);
this.form.get('csv').setValue(this.file);
return data;
}

// On Submit Method
onSubmit() {
this.uploadData.append('device_name', this.form.get('device_name').value);
this.uploadData.append('csv', this.form.get('csv').value);

this.backendService.insertCSV(this.uploadData).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
);
}

 // Call to Backend
HttpUploadOptions =
new HttpHeaders({
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
});
insertCSV(fileData): Observable<any> {
for (const iterator of Array.from(fileData.entries())) {
  console.log(iterator);
}
// Prints Below on Browser console
// (2) ["csv", File(168761)]
// (2) ["device_name", "Zephyr"]

return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/', { data: 
fileData, headers: this.HttpUploadOptions});
}
```

[Gives an Error on Console in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQrYe.png)

And Prints on Django

```
{u'headers': {u'normalizedNames': {}, u'lazyUpdate': None}, u'data': {}}
```

Please Help Me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that, following lines are not waiting for the `callback` on `reader.onload` to finish. Meaning file upload is not finished. Move them inside the `reader.onload` function.

```
// On Change Method
onFileChange(evt: any) {

 if (evt.target.files && evt.target.files[0]) {
  const file = evt.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = () => {
   this.form.get('csv').setValue(file);
   reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
   this.uploadData.append('csv', this.form.get('csv').value);
  };

 }
}
```

Comment: I have updated code. But something is still weird. It worked just once. And then now when I send File with the name it throws an error with status 0. and when I send the empty request I am able to see 

<QueryDict: {u'csv': [u'null'], u'device_name': 
[u'null']}>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with React and Django. Turns out, when using a **multipart/form-data** with front-end, **you shouldn't set the header**:

```
 // Call to Backend
HttpUploadOptions =
new HttpHeaders({
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
});
```

Not even **content-type: ''**, completely remove it. You have to let the browser set it, since they also add the **boundary** to it.

[More information](https://muffinman.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/) about why not to set it:

> What is boundary and why I had to delete the header?
>
> Multipart form allow transfer of binary data, therefore server needs a
>   way to know where one field’s data ends and where the next one starts.
>
> That’s where boundary comes in. It defines a delimiter between fields
>   we are sending in our request (similar to & for GET requests). You can
>   define it yourself, but it is much easier to let browser do it for
>   you.